# Format javascript array with multiple key and value

Tags: javascript, arrays

So after i got all data separately how can i organize my array look like this:

```
var arr = [{_1489378560544_544 : [customer_group_id : 0 , permission_id : 'permission_id'] }]
```

Here is my javascript get data function:

```
$('#category_permission > tbody > tr').each(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var customer_group_id = $(this).children('td:first').children('select:first').val();
            var permission_id = $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').children('select:first').val();
        });
```

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think array is not keys and values. object only have keys and values.so use like this

```
var arr=[];
    var n =[];

    $('#category_permission > tbody > tr').each(function() {
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                var customer_group_id = $(this).children('td:first').children('select:first').val();
                var permission_id = $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').children('select:first').val();

          var  inside = {
           customer_group_id : customer_group_id,
            permission_id: permission_id,
            }
            n.push(inside)
               var k ={
               _1489378560544_544:n,
               }
             arr.push(k)  
              });

    console.log(arr)
```

```js
var arr = [{
  _1489378560544_544: [{customer_group_id: 0, permission_id: 'permission_id'}]
}]

console.log(arr)
```

It give the result look like this